# Export Maya scene to Three.js

Tags: three.js, maya, scene, exporter

Is there any way to export the whole scene from `Maya` to `Three.js.`

**Exported elements should be:**
all mesh, textures, cameras, including the lights, shadows etc.

So that I can get the proper rendered effect that is been in the maya.

Comment: There is a Maya Exporter in Three.js ,but is there an option to export the whole scene

Answer (score 5):

If you read the doc for the [Maya exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya), it currently doesn't support exporting lights. You'll have to create the manually in your three.js code.

I don't know the current status of three.js loaders as I havn't used for a while now but back then Collada and FBX exporters were shaky. [And still seem to be.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx) You can try exporting from Maya to FBX and convert it (FBX file format supports lights).

OBJ file format doesn't support support lights of animation but this is the easiest way to go.

Long story short, export your models with the correct materials and create and place your lights manually.

PS: You can't export shadows.